# React native- task $ not found, cant launch app

Tags: android, windows, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Im trying to launch my work application on my windows laptop, other projects are working while this specific one continues to fail, this is the command:

```
 react-native run-android --variant=appDebug --appIdSuffix app
```

and the error message:

```
 Task '$' not found in root project 'My-App'
```

Im using latest android studio version and gradle 6.3.
If im trying to "build" the project via android studio, I'm getting this error

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
 com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index at
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419) at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352) at
 com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.(IndexCounters.java:34)
 at
 com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.(MapReduceIndex.java:92)
 at
 com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.(MapReduceIndex.java:108)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:274)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:110)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:13)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:80)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:152)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:361)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:140)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:297)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```